# SSIS ole db source using stored procedure cannot retrieve meta-data for columns

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, ssis

I'm using a stored procedure for ole db source in SSIS. It always pops out error when I click on "Columns" panel.  However, the same query executes successfully in SSMS and in "Build Query..." window. 
[image]

In the stored proc., no temp table but table variable is used. I did a lot research online but all similar cases seem to be caused by temp tables.

Comment: Did you try applying the same solutions that are recommended when temp tables are involved?

Comment: Yes, I tried to use "SET FMTONLY OFF
SET NOCOUNT ON
EXEC [dbo].[AR_XXXX]"  OR “IF 1=2 Begin EXEC dbo.AR_XXX END" But neither works

Comment: What about "IF 1=2 SELECT ..." and use the column list that will be returned by the proc.

Comment: You mean just to select from the source tables used in the stored proc?   I have tried that and both tables are accessible even without "IF 1=2". However, I cannot apply the whole logic in stored proc. to a single "Select" statement since it's quite complex

Answer (score 2):

For SSIS to use a stored proc as a datasource, the stored proc has to result in only one possible resultset structure.

You can let SSIS see the meta data for a complex stored proc by starting with something like this:

```
IF 1=2
 SELECT
   1 AS MyIntColumn
 , 1.11 AS MyMoneyColumn
 , 'test' AS MyVarcharColumn
ELSE
 BEGIN
 ...
```

The thing is to put in a SELECT statement in the 1=2 block that would return the Columns and the DataTypes that your stored procedure will ultimately return.   That way SSIS can look at that first statement and know what columns and datatypes to expect from the stored proc.   That's all it needs.  It doesn't need "real" data in that first select.  It can be all dummy values that don't even come from a table.

Comment: Thx for your answer! Yes in the stored procedure there is "IF.. ELSE" statement to direct different result sets ( but in same schema). What's weird is the same query ("exec dbo.AR_XXX") does not cause any error in VS 2008, while showing problems in VS 2012 as described.